# Jplayer won't work with some mp3 (MPEG 2.5 Layer III)

Tags: mp3, mime-types, codec, jplayer, hippocms

I have a problem with some mp3 uploaded to my server (Hippo CMS).

some of those mp3 are detected with a mime type :

- audio/mpeg   :  I don't have a problem with those files

other mp3 are detected with a mime type :

- video/x-mpeg  :  then I can't download those file anymore, nor use them with our audio-player (jplayer http://jplayer.org/)

Do you know how's the mime type detected and assigned to a file ?

If I look closer to those files,

- ok files are encoded with codec MPEG 1 Layer III
- wrong files are encoded with codec MPEG 2.5 Layer III

Which versions of mp3 are supported by jplayer ?
Is the problem at jplayer level or at detection of the mime type ?

EDIT: on Firefox I have following error

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/x-mpeg" is not supported. 
Load of media resource 
http://localhost:18080/site/binaries/content/assets/corporate-en/finance/podcasts/20140702-replay.mp3 failed.
```

and in chrome :

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
http://localhost:18080/site/binaries/content/assets/corporate-en/finance/podcasts/20140702-replay.mp3
```

Comment: same error with jplayer.